# Porque ocorre "undefined" mesmo definindo o elemento exato a ser atingido?

Tags: javascript, undefined

Estou aplicando uma [injeção](https://web.archive.org/web/20200929111638/https://pt.wikihow.com/Usar-Inje%C3%A7%C3%B5es-de-JavaScript) na barra de endereço do navegador web, sobre a página de um vídeo no youtube, no qual desejo extrair a data da postagem do mesmo.

Se abrirmos este [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z8WyxwuvYpk) vemos uma `div` similar a esta:

[image]

Ao selecionarmos a **data da postagem** e em seguida usar a ferramenta "View Selection Source" disponível no próprio navegador web, podemos ver o código-fonte da linha selecionada:

[image]
<sub>(fonte: [mplayerplugin @ sites.google.com](https://sites.google.com/site/mplayerplugin/screenshots/Screenshot.png))</sub>

De posse do nome da classe `watch-time-text`, tentei fazer o seguinte:

```
javascript:postado=document.getElementsByClassName("watch-time-text").innerHTML; alert(postado);
```

E ocorreu o seguinte:

[image]
<sub>(fonte: [mplayerplugin @ sites.google.com](https://sites.google.com/site/mplayerplugin/screenshots/Screenshot-2.png))</sub>

Porque ocorre esse `undefined` mesmo o elemento existindo na pagina?

## <strike>Porque um gif vale mais do que mil palavras</strike>

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

O método [`getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) retorna uma coleção de elementos e não um elemento apenas.

Se você tem certeza que só existe um elemento com esta classe pode usar o índice 0 pra obtê-lo.

```
postado = document.getElementsByClassName("watch-time-text")[0].innerHTML;
alert(postado);
```

Comment: Claro, eu que agradeço! E olha que agora funcionou com sua dica. Receba meu upVote seguido do Voto absoluto. E novamente meu síncero agradecimentos.

Comment: Sempre bom poder ajudar =)